# calculating mass of galaxy from luminosity

Tags: observational-astronomy, galaxy, astrophysics

A very elementary question, just to make sure I got this thing right.
Suppose we are given that the mass to luminosity ratio of a galaxy is $2 \frac{M_{\odot}}{L_{\odot}}$.

Let us say, that the luminosity of the galaxy = $L = 100\,L_{\odot}/pc^2$.

Then the mass density of the galaxy  = $\rho = 100 L_{\odot}/pc^2 \times 2 \frac{M_{\odot}}{L_{\odot}} = 200 M_{\odot}/pc^2$.

Is this the right calculation?

Comment: The mass surface density.